# SQL Server 2017 Express missing from visual studio setup wizard prerequisites

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio, setup-project

I have installed Microsoft [Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects#qna), but SQL Server 2017 express is missing from prerequisite
[image]

How to add SQL Server 2017 Express? (I'm using WPF project with .NET Framework 4.6.1).
I tried SQL Server 2012 Express and got the following error:

> WARNING: Item 'SQL Server 2012 Express' could not find any of dependent items '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5, .NETFramework,Version=v4.0'.
>
> ERROR: To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'SqlExpress2012\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.EXE' for item 'SQL Server 2012 Express' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018.

Thanks.